# String Sorter Returing Exit Code 0 instead of the Strings

Tags: java, string, user-input

I am trying to make a string sorter that takes user input and puts it into alphabetical order. My code looks like this:

```
public class StringSorter {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 1);
        System.out.println("How many strings do you want to sort?");
        int numStrings = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        System.out.println("Input Strings Here:");
        String[] stringsToSort = new String[numStrings];
        for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
            String s = stdin.readLine();
            stringsToSort[i] = s;
        }
        int comparison = (stringsToSort[0].compareToIgnoreCase(stringsToSort[1]));
        if (stringsToSort[0].compareToIgnoreCase(stringsToSort[1]) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Alphabetical Order: " + Integer.toString(comparison));
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it print the strings instead of "Exit Code 0"?
I forgot to add that I cannot use java.util.Arrays or java.util.Vector for this assignment

Comment: It works for me, how are you executing this code?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are printing the result of a comparison and not the string and you're only sorting the two first strings.

You call `Array.sort()` first and then you print the array. Replace your comparison and print with

```
Arrays.sort(stringsToSort);

for (String string : stringsToSort) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is going to print 1, if the first String is alphabetically smaller than the second String otherwise it will do nothing and return 0 exit code.
 If you intend to do is print the array, you should iterate using a for loop on the elements of the array and print the element.

For sorting the array, you could use any of the sorting algos. Selection sort is the simplest to understand. Following is a link for sorting a String array.
http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~smkautz/cs227f12/examples/week11/SelectionSortExamples.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sorting like this for your one,

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 1);
        System.out.println("How many strings do you want to sort?");
        int numStrings = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        System.out.println("Input Strings Here:");
        String[] stringsToSort = new String[numStrings];
        for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
            String s = stdin.readLine();
            stringsToSort[i] = s;
        }

        Arrays.sort(stringsToSort, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < stringsToSort.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(stringsToSort[i]);
        }
    }

}
```